# mix mash of code doesn't work in FF

Tags: firefox, forms, doctype

I know this page is a mash of different things and breaks many rules but it's a short term solution till the new quiz system is made. I did this quiz system on another site and it worked but when bringing it over to this site FF3 (maybe others) have stopped submitting the code. I have since worked out it's because of the doctype.
Can anyone suggest how to just get it going again keeping in mind that if I change the docotype to the usual 4.01 transitional the site goes bunta in ie6 :(
http://abc.net.au/news/btn/quiz/index.html?file=js/2009-08sugaryinventions.js

I know this is quite vague a question but I think it has something to do with the form/input submit combo...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it was a messy question so thanks to those (all 12 of you) that at least looked :)
The answer lay in needing to totally declare all the variables in the js:

`buttons.style.display='none';`

to

`document.getElementById("buttons").style.display='none';`

Thanks to someone at work who helped me there.